# Which scrolls will monsters read?

Tags: nethack

I just got the message

```
You hear a leprechaun reading a scroll labeled FOOBIE BLETCH.
```

I know that monsters can read scrolls of create monster (which I've identified) and teleportation (which I haven't).

Is it safe to assume that this was a scroll of teleportation (it's a leprechaun hall, so I can't tell whether one of them teleported with telepathy since several have already used their innate teleportation ability)? Or are there other scrolls that monsters will read?

In short, I'm looking for a **list of scrolls that monsters can read**. I'm almost positive I've seen a list like this before, but the wiki pages for [scroll](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Scroll), [monster](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Monster), and [read](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Read) don't mention anything about monster use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monsters can read scrolls of teleportation, create monster and earth.  The source includes code to allow monsters to read scrolls of fire, but it's not compiled into the game executable (it's enclosed in `#if 0`).

The relevant source code is in [muse.c](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Source:NetHack_3.4.3/src/muse.c) at line 222 and line 943.  The `#define`s relating to scrolls (which constitute a complete list of the scrolls possibly used by monsters) are

```
#define MUSE_SCR_TELEPORTATION 1
#define MUSE_SCR_CREATE_MONSTER 11

#define MUSE_SCR_FIRE 8
#define MUSE_SCR_EARTH 17
```

which are referenced from the [`find_defensive`](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Source:NetHack_3.4.3/src/muse.c#find_defensive), [`use_defensive`](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Source:NetHack_3.4.3/src/muse.c#use_defensive), [`find_offensive`](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Source:NetHack_3.4.3/src/muse.c#find_offensive) and [`use_offensive`](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Source:NetHack_3.4.3/src/muse.c#use_offensive) functions in the same file.

Comment: Hmm, after a bit of investigation, all references to `MUSE_SCR_FIRE` seem to be in commented-out `#if 0` blocks. Hence, monsters will only use teleportation, create monster, and (occasionally) earth. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how the source code you quoted is related to your answer. Those are just constant definitions that have no meaning without context. More relevant are the chunks of code labelled find_defensive and find_offensive. The specific items are mentioned on lines 464, 511, 1066, and 1083.

Comment: @murgatroid99: They're a complete list of the scrolls referenced from `find_defensive` and `find_offensive`.  If you just want a list, looking at the `#define`s is easier than reading those large functions, and grepping for the defines will show specifically where they're used.

Comment: I see your point, but my point is still that those lines don't mean anything included in this answer. Also, Doorknob has a point: the lines that actually check for fire scrolls are removed by the precompiler.